# PHP - Trying to access a value in an object

Tags: php, arrays, json

It's a woocommerce object called `$_product`

When I `var_dump` it I get:

```
object(WC_Product_Variation)#4358 (13) {
  ["post_type":protected]=>
  string(17) "product_variation"
  ["parent_data":protected]=>
  array(16) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Antares"
    ["status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(0) ""
```

When I `echo $_product->post_type;` I get `product_variation` as expected, but I can't access the status value!

`var_dump($_product->parent_data);` gives me nothing (empty)

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `protected` properties outside of the object instance or its parent instances. See [Property Visibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) on php.net for more info.

So why is it possible to access the `$post_type` even though it's `protected`? Well, someone was "smart" enough to define an exception from the rule in this magic getter method - https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-legacy-abstract-wc-legacy-product.html#source-view.68

This is a bad practice and should not be used.

Instead, you can create your own class that extends the `WC_Product_Variation` and defines its own public getters `getPostType()` and `getParentData()`. Just don't forget to instantiate the `MyWC_Product_Variation` instead of `WC_Product_Variation` when you want to use the getters.

```
class MyWC_Product_Variation extends WC_Product_Variation
{
    public function getPostType(): string
    {
        return $this->post_type;
    }

    public function getParentData(): array
    {
        return $this->parent_data;
    }
}
```